# Using "options" in pickStringwith multi arguments

Tags: visual-studio-code

I didn't find a way to get through this... Here is an example :

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "listCommands",
            "type": "pickString",
            "options": [
                "simpleCommand",
                "commandWithArg args1"
            ]
         }
    ]
}
```

When launching, vscode create the command

```sh
$ whatever "commandWithArg args1"
```

with the `"`.

How to define an option with argument(s) ?
I've tried something like this

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "listCommands",
            "type": "pickString",
            "options": [
                ["commandWithArg", "args1"]
            ]
         }
    ]
}
```

but no way.... vscode just yelled at me :) :

[image]

Same with `{label, value}` syntax :

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "listCommands",
            "type": "pickString",
            "options": [
                {"label": "my_label", "value": ["commandWithArg", "args1"]}
            ]
         }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable)

Use the commands `extension.commandvariable.pickStringRemember` and `extension.commandvariable.remember`, see the [3rd example](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#pickstringremember) with the multiple values.